# Concurrent calls in WCF RIA not working

Tags: wcf-ria-services

We are using Silverlight 4.0 with WCF RIA services.
One thing we noticed is that we are not able to make simultaneous service calls to the server.
Our WCF RIA service have 2 methods method1 and method2. What we noticed is that, the calls are sequential, i.e method2 is not executed until method1 comes back.

Do we need to change any configuration in the web config to make simultaneous calls work ?

Thanks !

Comment: One thing i just tried is removing the Glbal.asax file from the web project and that made simultaneous calls working ! But i really need the Global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved swithing that calls on the ClientStack.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2009/09/30/having-a-pollingduplex-service-and-any-other-wcf-service-in-the-same-website-causes-silverlight-calls-to-be-slow.aspx) ther's a long and clear explanation on what happens!

Hope this helps!